# What's the best rewording of "midas harachamim aleinu hisgalgli" for those uncomfortable with it?

Tags: yom-kippur, prayer-book, theology, selichot

In the Selichot (fifth day of Aseret Yimei Teshuvah, HaPizmon shel Yud Gimel Middot HaRahamim) and in Ne'ila of Yom Kippur, there's the stanza that [reads](https://books.google.com/books?id=cJdLAAAAIAAJ&dq=Seder%20selihoth%20k%CA%BBminhag%20Polin%20gadol%20uFolin%20katan&pg=PA83&ci=112%2C904%2C816%2C210&source=bookclip#v=onepage&q&f=false):

[image]

The concern is the few middle lines:

> מדת הרחמים עלינו התגלגלי
>
> ולפני קונך תחנתנו הפילי
>
> ובעד עמך רחמים שאלי

Which *sounds like* we're addressing G-d's mercy as separate from G-d, asking her to beseech G-d on our behalf.  For those uncomfortable with this concept theologically (or unwilling to give the liturgy some artistic license), what's the best rewording here?  The stanza ends with the Biblical   וכל ראש לחלי  so anything would either have to match that (ending in "lee"); paraphrase the verse differently; or break the rhyme.

Comment: The rewording would need to cover a few lines. Take  a look at the seliha again and you will see.

Comment: If the text is not meant as artistic license, who amongst our traditional sources would not have a problem with it?

Comment: See the sources cited in note 40 here: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32573&st=&pgnum=332 (the Chabad machzor for Yom Kippur). There are indeed respectable opinions on both sides of the issue; those (including of course the original paytan) who defend this wording explain that we are asking the Thirteen Middos to act as a conduit for Hashem's beneficence, but not that we impute any independent powers to them, chas veshalom.

Comment: Yahu, I like the Google bookclip!  Alex, neat idea just taking the jpg!  I've added in the Hebrew text here (sans vowels) to make it more searchable; but I think all three ways to do it are good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Hebrew Publishing Company machzor of 1926 ("reprinted from the latest and best London edition") has [the following](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33441&pgnum=690) ([image of relevant stanza](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sIIU.png)), which clearly addresses HaShem (and later one's own soul) rather than His attribute of mercy:

> רַחֲמֶיךָ עָלֵינוּ גּלְגֵּל נָא גֹאֲלִי׃
>
> לְפָנָיו נַפְשִׁי תְּחִנָּתִךְ הַפִּילִּי׃
>
> וּבְעַד עַמִּי רַחֲמִים שַׁאֲלִי׃
>
> כִּי כָל לֵבָב דַּוָּי וְכָל רָאשׁ לָחֳלִי׃

Comment: Addressing your own soul in the feminine; interesting.  (As done in <a href="http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2642.htm">Psalms 42:6</a> and elsewhere.)  I *knew* there had to be some variant texts out there!

Comment: Woops.  Psalms 42:6, see for instance http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2642.htm