# Saying slichos at any time but "ashmores haboker", should we take out references to the early morning time so we are not "lying"?

Tags: tefilla, time, selichot, sheker-false

Many of the Slichos refer to the early morning time: "Ashmores Haboker", which is clearly not applicable to those who say late slichos (say at 8 AM) or who say it early at night (say at 10 PM, let's leave out the discussion of the appropriateness of saying slichos before Chatzos, which relates to another thread).

Should people saying slichos at other times remove such phrases? (It doesn't seem to be what is done commonly, and it seems to me like an inaccurate statement to say that "I have come in the early morning to beseech you" when this is not the case.)

Further, in today's slichos, it said "Shachar Kamti", and at the 10 PM slichos that I was at, they all screamed that out as usual without noticing the inaccuracy. After all, we were NOT "Shachar Kamti", (in fact we were not "Kamti" at all for slichos but were already up all day) but rather chose the questionable but very convenient 10 PM time! Should we have omitted those words?

Comment: kinda similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15179/759

Answer (score 2):

References to times other than the recitation should be omitted ([*Aruch HaShulchan*, OC 581:4](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Arukh_ha-Shulchan/Orach_Chaim/581?match=he)). However, whether a reference is incorrect should probably not be judged at first glance. For example, *shachar kamti* can mean nighttime rather than early morning, so it should be recited even at night.

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps the next editions of the Slichos should "flag" those words that people need to consider before saying them. It seems most people are unaware of this and I am yet to find a minyan where this was done.

Comment: @aaron Yes, including that in the siddur would be a good idea.

Comment: @aaron In Ner Israel, there was a list put up every year with a list of changes to make in the selichos for the first night.  (The rest were done in the morning, and therefore no changes for that reason were necessary after the first night.)